# After updating from Visual Studio 2019 to 2022, my blazor server side web app cannot be opened. I get FileNotFoundException. How to fix?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, blazor-server-side, visual-studio-2022, filenotfoundexception

I have a Blazor Server side app created with Visual Studio 2019 (.NetCore 3.1). The app was working fine until now. I updated my Visual Studio to 2022. After opening the project I noticed that Framework was set to .Net 6.0, so I changed it manually to .NetCore 3.1 and published the project without any errors.

But when I tried to open the webpage, unfortunately I got the following Error on my Browser. What can I do now? I have just updated Visual Server to 2022, nothing else.

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

at System.Text.Json.JsonReaderHelper.IndexOfOrLessThan(Byte& searchSpace, Byte value0, Byte value1, Byte lessThan, Int32 length)
at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeString()
at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumePropertyName()
at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 utf8JsonSpan, Utf8JsonReader reader, MetadataDb& database, StackRowStack& stack)
at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlyMemory`1 utf8Json, JsonReaderOptions readerOptions, Byte[] extraRentedBytes)
at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(ReadOnlyMemory`1 json, JsonDocumentOptions options)
at System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(String json, JsonDocumentOptions options)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationFileParser.ParseStream(Stream input)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(Stream stream)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo info)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
at WebApplication7.Program.Main(String[] args) in W:\00_md91bu_Projects\30_ConCheetahPortal_Blazor\WebApplication7\Program.cs:line 23
```

Update:1 I have cleaned, rebuild and published the project from another remote PC with the same version of VS2022, but still the same.

Comment: Where did you publish it? Azzure? AWS? Local  folder?

Comment: @MayurEkbote   Published to local folder on the same server

Comment: You said it went to .NET6, and you changed it manually to .NETCore 3.1, but did you do the same for the nuget packages ? I guess, their versions might be bound to the .Net version.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Ok, got you, no i didn't do that for the nugget packages. But how can I understand which nuggets are used only by this project? I mean if there are common used nuggets, what should I do?

Comment: Something is probably still targetting .Net6 judging by the version of the package missing (V6.0.0.0). The packages used by your project are referenced in your .csproj file. You could also try to clean and rebuild your solution.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Last question: I have looked to the references of the project. There are a lot of nuggets referenced. When I open the VS2019 created project with VS2022 are the nuggets automatically transfered to VS2022 or do I have to install them manually?

Comment: I am not sure. They are stored in ~/.nuget/ folder.

Comment: Right click on the project -> select "Nuget manager for the project" (not Console) and individually check each dependency. Downgrade any dependency on 6.0.0 to 3.1

Comment: @MayurEkbote There is one problem. If I look to the dependencies of the project there are some with V6.0.0 but I can downgrade them min. to 4.X.X. On most of them there is no 3.1 version.  And additionally: If I look to the dependencies of the previous versions of my project which were just opened with VS2019 (and still working fine) there are exactly the same dependencies. I mean with opening the project with VS2022 the dependencies haven't changed.

Comment: Right click on the project and click on properties. There will be an option called "Target Framework" change it to .net core 3.1 Keep in mind that some of your dependencies might not even support  anything lower than .net 5 (there  were a few breaking changes)

Comment: @MayurEkbote Excuse me very much but setting the target framework to 3.1, I have done at first. Have written also in the problem discription.